# How do I enable a button when a HTML text turns to the value of 1?

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

I am making a game called [2048 Bitcoin](https://www.2048bitcoin.tk) and I am trying to disable this code: `<a id="restart-button" class="restart-button">Cash Out</a>` and then enable it as soon as `<div class="satoshis-container">0</div>` is equal to 1 or more. But I tried doing this and it didn't work:

In index.html: 
`<a id="restart-button" class="restart-button" disabled>Cash Out</a>`

In js/grid.js (in the part that removes a tile):

```
Grid.prototype.removeTile = function (tile) {
  this.cells[tile.x][tile.y] = null;
  if (document.querySelector("#satoshis-container").value > 1) {
    document.querySelector("#restart-button").disabled = false;
  }
};
```

How do I disable a button and re-enable it when my container has a value of 0?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an if on a boolean, but your div does not have a value. Try this, where I cast the string content to a number using an unary plus sign

```
Grid.prototype.removeTile = function (tile) {
  this.cells[tile.x][tile.y] = null;
  document.querySelector("#restart-button").disabled = +document.querySelector("#satoshis-container").textContent < 1;
};
```

Comment: I have one question, do I put the disabled attribute in index.html? Or should I just put that.

Comment: Also, what is the textContent < 1, does it mean that it will be enabled if the #satoshis-container is above 1? Sorry, I am just a beginner, and I don't really know this stuff.

Comment: Yes it will be enabled. Where to put the code? You showed the code and I changed ti . Bedtime

Comment: It ended up breaking the game and not updating the score and satoshi count, and I can still click on the button to cash out.

Comment: Then it is in the wrong place or not correctly implemented. Hard to tell